# What am I doing wrong?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Verb meaning "redeemed", but without implying a previous corruption](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229381/what-is-the-antonym-of-the-past-tense-verb-corrupted?noredirect=1#229381)

Boring meta question: my question got put "on hold", but I don't see what's wrong with it. Thesaurus and Lexipedia don't have anything, so it's not a case of "didn't do basic research". Where's my error?

I'm totally willing to fix it, but I don't know how.

Comment: What was wrong was looking for an antonym of a word like that. The way the question is phrased now is much better! :)

Answer (score 4):

You have a good start. You should cite your sources and possibly change the title from 'antonym of corrupt' to your specific question 'going from good to better', although I think paralleling *corrupt* with what you are looking for is useful. Antonym questions are treated poorly around here. Also, adding an example sentence or two with a blank will help establish the context for the word you are seeking. The headline example you give is good, but make that more obvious.

The [tag wiki](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for single word requests should help you out here. I think you've almost got it.

Comment: Thanks. I've re-worked it. Hopefully it's better (though wordier.)

Comment: @Sean It's a site about language and usage. Wordy is often better here.